# Javascript number counter with breakss

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script for to increment a counter by one after 1 second, I need it to be updated 5 by 5 every second: 1, 6, 11, 16, etc.

```js
function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
  setInterval(function() {
    current++;
    // Update the contents of the element
    obj.innerHTML = current;
  }, 1000);
}

animateValue('value');
```

```html
<h1>
  <div id="value">1</div>
</h1>
```

Comment: then you would add 5 instead of 1 - my guess is, you can't see where it's adding one? `++`

Comment: change `current++` to be `current = current + 5`

Answer (score 0):

Change the timer from 1000 to 5000 and change ++ to +=5, and that should update by 5 every 5 seconds.

```js
function animateValue(id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
  setInterval(function() {
    current += 5;
    // Update the contents of the element
    obj.innerHTML = current;
  }, 5000);
}

animateValue('value');
```

```html
<h1>
  <div id="value">1</div>
</h1>
```